# Send email to a list - R

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I have a database in R with a list of email addresses (several on each row). I would like to be able to send a template email to each row with some varying elements in the text (name, action required).

I was thinking to use a function with the `RDCOMClient` package. As I do not have any code to provide, there is no need to reply with a code, just ideas of how I could solve this problem.

Comment: `OutApp  <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application");
    outMail <- OutApp$CreateItem(0);
    outMail[["To"]]       = paste([VECTOR OF EMAILS HERE], collapse = ';')`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could either

1. modify this to run inside of a loop that runs on each row of your database/`data.frame` or
2. Just put all the emails into `to = c()`

   ```
   pacman::p_load(mailR)
   send.mail(from = "Some Name <whatever@address.net>",
         to = c( "user.email@goes_here.net", "another@address.net"),
         subject="Scoring Completed!",
         body = "This is the answer to your question!!",
         smtp = list(host.name = "host.domain", port = 25),
         authenticate = FALSE,
         send = TRUE)
   ```

I am sure you can do it with the library you mentioned, but that 1 is very old and not on CRAN, so maybe you'd prefer to use `mailR` or `gmailR` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good start for you.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
## init com api
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## create an email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## configure  email parameter 
outMail[["To"]] = "receiver@gmail.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "some subject"
outMail[["body"]] = "some body"
## send it                     
outMail$Send()
```

I just tested it and it works fine for me.